# Pointer to array has the same value as array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The code below creates an array and a pointer that points to it. Then the program prints out the content of the two variables. The curious thing is that the memory addresses printed out are the same, even though they shouldn't. `ptr` should contain the *address* of `array`, not `array` itself. Can anybody explain this please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char array[] = "abcdefg";
    char (*ptr)[] = &array;

    printf("%p\n", array);
    printf("%p\n", ptr);
}
```

Comment: Your first printf call prints the address of the array as well.

Comment: @immibis Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `array` is converted to `&array[0]` most times by the compiler.

Comment: Look up array to pointer decay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [*Pointers to arrays in C*](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/11/pointers-to-arrays-in-c) by Eli Bendersky:

> Consider this code:
>
> ```
> void test(int** p)
> {
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5};
>     test(&arr);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> `gcc` isn't very happy about it, and issues a warning: `passing arg 1
>   of test from incompatible pointer type`. C++ has stricter type
>   checking, so let's try running the same code through `g++`. As
>   expected, we get an error: `cannot convert int (*)[4] to int** for
>   argument 1 to void test(int**)`.
>
> So what's the problem here? What's wrong with the code above? Well,
>   everything. It's simply invalid, and it makes no sense. Some would
>   think it should work because this works:
>
> ```
> void test(int* p)
> {
>
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5};
>     test(arr);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> But this one works specifically because the C compilers should follow
>   the C standard, which mandates that arrays "decay" into pointers when
>   used as lvalues. Thus, a pointer to the array's first element is
>   actually passed to test and everything works.
>
> However, the first code snippet is different. While an array name may
>   decay into a pointer, the address of the array does not decay into a
>   pointer to a pointer. And why should it? What sense does it make to
>   treat an array so?
>
> Pointers to pointers are sometimes passed to modify the pointers
>   (simple pointer arguments don't work here because C passes by value,
>   which would only allow to modify what's pointed, not the pointer
>   itself). Here's some imaginary code (won't compile):
>
> ```
> void test(int** p)
> {
>     *p = malloc ... /* retarget '*p' */
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5};
>     int* ptr;
>
>     /* Fine!
>     ** test will retarget ptr, and its new value
>     ** will appear after this call.
>     */
>     test(&ptr);
>
>     /* Makes no sense!
>     ** You cannot retarget 'arr', since it's a
>     ** constant label created by the compiler.
>     */
>     test(&arr);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> ## Pointers to arrays
>
> Note that the original code could be modified a little to make it
>   work:
>
> ```
> void test(int (*p)[4])
> {
>     (*p)[2] = 10;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     int arr[] = {30, 450, 14, 5};
>
>     test(&arr);
>     printf("%d\n", arr[2]);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> What is that weird type test accepts now? Say hello to a "pointer to
>   array", one of the useless features of C. This is what the C FAQ has
>   to say about it:
>
> > ## 2.12: How do I declare a pointer to an array?
> >
> > Usually, you don't want to. When people speak casually of a pointer to
> >     an array, they usually mean a pointer to its first element.
>
> While the test function from the previous snippet compiles and works,
>   it isn't of much use, since it's much clearer to write:
>
> ```
> void test(int* p)
> {
>     p[2] = 10;
> }
>
> ...
> ...
> /* then call */
> test(arr);
> ```
>
> The main use of pointers as function arguments is to either avoid
>   passing whole structures by value, or to modify the object pointed by
>   the pointers. Both are irrelevant needs for pointers to array. Here's
>   a clarifying snippet:
>
> ```
> int joe[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
>
> void test(int (*p)[4])
> {
>     /* Fine: assign to an element through the
>     ** pointer.
>     */
>     (*p)[2] = 10;
>
>     /* Works, but won't be reflected in the
>     ** caller since p was passed by value.
>     */
>     p = &joe;
>
>     /* Error: arrays can't be assigned.
>     */
>     *p = joe;
> }
> ```
>
> Arrays are not passed by value anyway, so a pointer to an array is
>   useless for this purpose. Neither can arrays be modified, so that
>   kills the second reason.

To answer the question, the reason for `&array` to be equal to `array` is because `array` is a "constant label created by the compiler," not a pointer variable. So it actually makes no sense to "dereference" `array` and the compiler happens to simply return the value of `array` itself whenever this happens.

Answer (score 1):

For any array named `array`, `array` and `&array` has the same value - the address of the first element of the array. Just their types are different - `array` here has type `char *`, where are `&array` has type `char(*)[]`.

Answer (score 0):

For an example consider the array as `char a[10];`

when we are assigning to the pointer variable we assign as `char *ptr=a`

we can also assign like `ptr=&a[0];` so the both statements are same the two will refer the starting address of the array

Answer (score -1):

`array` doesn't have an address, in the way that, say, `ptr` has an address. Because an array always points to the same memory location, there's no need for that memory location to be stored in some *other* memory location. There's no way to take `array` and get a temporary `char**` such that `(*char)[0] == 'a'`.

So `&array` has type `char(*)[]`, and returns the location of the first `char` in the array. Likewise, `array`, when used in a pointer context (that is to say, pretty much everywhere, with a couple of exceptions), has the same effect as `&array` but with different type. This is known as "array decay".

More information at [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Comment: "array doesn't have an address" Every variable has an address. Its value is not an address. "Because an array always points to the same memory location" An array is a sequence of elements; it doesn't "point". "There's no way to take array and get a temporary char**" Right, because that's a pointer to pointer, not pointer to array. "So &array has type char(*)[], and returns the location of the first char in the array." No, it returns a pointer to the array.